# How to change dynamic HTML button onClick event with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have codes :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="modal-footer" >
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="mybutton" style="background-color: #367E2D; color:white; opacity: 1" onclick="chooseme();">OK</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript :**

```
('#mybutton').click(chooseme('123'));
```

**Purpose :**

I want to change `onClick` event from `chooseme()` to `chooseme('123')` using Javascript

**And the result of the code above is :**

chooseme('123') executed immediately (not when the button clicked)

> Question is : Anyone can explain what's wrong with my code? and what is
>   the correct implementation to reach the purpose above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume from the syntax that you're using jQuery. When binding events to named functions in JS, you need to pass the function itself to the callback. With your current syntax, you're passing the **return value** from `chooseme()` to the `click` handler. As a result, the function is called immediately on page load.

Wrap the hander inside an anonymous function, and you're good to go:

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function() { chooseme('123') });
```

Comment: sorry, i have found a problem, choseme executed twice. I don't have idea why. anyway thanks for your answer